# Topological space M with partition of unity--->M paracompact. John Lee Problems

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a topological space with the property that for every open cover $X$ of $M$, there exists a partition of unity subordinate to $X$. Show that $M$ is paracompact.

Answer (score 4):

$X=\lbrace X_a \rbrace$ and let $\lbrace P_a\rbrace$ be the *associated* partition of unity, the index set for both is $A$. Define $A'=\lbrace a|a\in A,P_a\neq 0\rbrace$ and finally define $V_a=P_a^{-1}(0,1]$ for $a\in A'$, open in $M$. It is easy to see that $\lbrace V_a|a\in A'\rbrace$ is a locally finite refinement.

Comment: Why is $V_a$ open? It’s the preimage of a set that’s not open nor closed in Standard topology.

Comment: Shouldn’t we define $V_a:=P_a^{-1}((0,1))$

Answer (score 2):

Given any covering $ \{U_\alpha \} $ you have the partition of unity $ \phi_\alpha $ such that $ V_\alpha = supp(\phi_\alpha ) \subset U_\alpha $ is a locally finite covering of $M$ (which is why we have the sum of $\phi_\alpha $ as a finite sum). Clearly $ \{V_\alpha \} $ is a refinement of $\{U_\alpha \}$. Thus any open cover has a locally finite refinement that covers $M$, hence $M$ is paracompact.

Comment: This isn’t quite enough: a regular space is paracompact if every open cover has a (not necessarily open) locally finite refinement, but the implication can fail in non-regular spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well you can take the interior of each $V_\alpha $ which also covers $M$, and they are not of empty interior from continuity of $\phi_\alpha $, So you have a locally finite open refinement which is the definition of paracompactness.

Comment: Yes, you can, but that has to be said.

Comment: Its really, take the interior of each $V_{\alpha}$ and problem is complete

Thanks very much .